# How can I both move a div and resize it with animation effect at JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, resize, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

How can I both move a div and resize it with animation effect at JQuery?

i.e. div will be at the middle of screen and it will go to the left side and will have %50 of its height and %50 of its width after it completed its move.(It will have for example %75 of its size at the middle of its way)

**EDIT:** I tried that:

```
$(".block").animate({"left": "-=100px", "height": "-=30%", "width":"-=30%" }, 1000);
```

However it disappears?

**EDIT2:**
This works:

```
$(".block").animate({"left": "-=100px", "height": "30%", "width":"30%" }, 1000);
```

However it makes my square more bigger, I try =-30% but doesn't work. What should I do getting smaller instead of getting bigger?

Comment: Best would be if you provide a running example, for example on jsfiddle.

Comment: Seems like the last line is setting the height and width css properties to 30%. You expect it to be 30% of the previous sizes, but it actually is 30% of the nearest sized parent of the block, which seems to be larger than the previous size.

Comment: @TonioElGringo so what should I do, is there a way to make it 30% of its original size?

Comment: @kamaci, I don't think there is a simple way to do this (like a special syntax in animate or so). I assume you have to code a javascript function that calculates the new width from the old one.

Comment: @TonioElGringo can you suggest anything else as like with JQuery Tools or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the last line is setting the height and width css properties to 30%. You expect it to be 30% of the previous sizes, but it actually is 30% of the nearest sized parent of the block, which seems to be larger than the previous size.

I don't think there is a simple way to resize to a given percentage of the previous size (like a special syntax in animate or so). I assume you have to code a javascript function that calculates the new width from the old one.

Given that you only want to resize one element, I strongly suggest that you use the element ID instead of its class. Then the following line should do what you want:

```
$("#block").animate({"left": "-=100px", "height": $("#block").height()*0.5, "width":$("#block").width()*0.5 }, 1000);
```

Comment: This works fine but if I write inside of that div, its size is still same. How can I resize that div with its elements. I mean the elements inside of it will be resized too?

Comment: You can add "font-size" to your animate function arguments. Have a look there: http://jsfiddle.net/T7c57/

Comment: Actually I want more. There will be buttons inside of that div and every button will have an image or something like that. I want that when you resize that div, every child of it should be resized too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animate function of jQuery. You can check this link:

```
  http://api.jquery.com/animate/
```

In the above link, examples shows you all the things which you want(like change the width with animation). Please check the example.

Comment: I have edited my question, I use animate but where is the wrong?